# Create maven project is on some PC

Tags: java, maven

**I try the steps in it work at Home , when I back to work and I encounter some new problems**

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project it

> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app
>   -DartifactId=Maven-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false I get the following errors

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metada
ta.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xm
l from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to: http
s://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml , R
easonPhrase:Forbidden.
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/
to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to: https://rep
o.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Fo
rbidden.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from h
ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resoluti
on will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or u
pdates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.
plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
): Access denied to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugi
ns/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will
 not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates
are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-
metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access deni
ed to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
 , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
```

**1) How do I test my proxy setting ? there is the username equals my PC login name?
2) How can it look for the repositories in C?**

```
No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the
 plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
 [local (C:\path\to\local\repo), central (https://repo.maven.apache.
org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

I have setting like, I though the repository suppose under my username

```
<!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository-->
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
```

Comment: **Access denied to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.**

Comment: I Know My problem on 2) How can it look for the repositories in C? I cause by I try and high version maven in my PC and did not delete the old one , how can I delete everything and reset Maven in my PC?

Comment: try offline probably